# ReCharts - How to set an offset for axes?

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap, recharts

I'm using openweathermap API to display temperature/day and the graph it produces cover a lot of unnecessary area.
I want to add an offset to the Y-axis... Let's say from 20 degrees onwards.
This is how it looks like right now:

And this is my code:

```
return (
  <div className="justify-content-center py-3">
    <div className="text-center">
      <AreaChart width={400} height={200} data={data2}>
        <XAxis dataKey="dt"/>
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip/>
        <Area type='monotone' dataKey='temp' stroke='#673AB7' fill='white' />
      </AreaChart>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Image of graph right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
<YAxis domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} />
```